# Get string from substring

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have following string `"@[Hema](hema_ramburuth), @[Ilesh P](ilesh.panchal), @[Lewis Murphy](lewis) how are you?"`. I want to display this screen like this `"Hema, Ilesh P, Lewis Murphy how are you?`" also I want to identify the screen for the click event.

I have used the [ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift) repo for the click.

Comment: What're `hema_ramburuth`, `ilesh.panchal` and `lewis`? Also please show your code what have you tried so far.

Comment: @TheTiger, It should be username.

Comment: I don't why these people gave the upvote for this question. There's no input what he tried. Also didn't ask complex scenario. (just substring without the format).

Comment: @PaulMarshal I know that I mean whether he wants the value from these variables or from square brackets? Or how the usernames are being passed to this string? This is not clear enough for me.

Comment: Is this fix how are you message is comes in last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I have had encountered a similar requirement. So this is how I have handled.

I have created an extension for `String`

```
extension String {
    /// Returns range of text in the string
    func getRange(OfText text: String) -> NSRange {
        let nsRepresentation = self as NSString
        return nsRepresentation.range(of: text)
    }
}
```

In your View Controller,

```
var tapPrivacyGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
@IBOutlet weak var yourLabel: UILabel!
var displayText = String()

func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String, text: String, firstBracket: String, lastBracket: String) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(
            in: text,
            options: [],
            range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range) }.map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: firstBracket, with: "") }.map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: lastBracket, with: "") }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

var givenString = "@[Hema](hema_ramburuth), @[Ilesh P](ilesh.panchal), @[Lewis Murphy](lewis) how are you?"
let nameStrings = matchesForRegexInText(regex: "\\[(.*?)\\]", text: givenString, firstBracket: "[", lastBracket: "]")
let removeForUIStrings = matchesForRegexInText(regex: "\\((.*?)\\)", text: givenString, firstBracket: "(", lastBracket: ")")

removeForUIStrings.forEach {
    givenString = givenString.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\($0))", with: "")
}
nameStrings.forEach {
    givenString = givenString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\($0)]", with: $0)
}
givenString = givenString.replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "")
print(givenString)
displayText = givenString

tapPrivacyGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlePolicyTap(tap:)))
yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapPrivacyGesture)
yourLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


func handlePolicyTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let storage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: yourLabel.attributedText ?? NSAttributedString())
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    storage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: yourLabel.frame.size.width, height: yourLabel.frame.size.height+100))
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = (yourLabel.lineBreakMode)
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = yourLabel.numberOfLines
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

    let location: CGPoint = tap.location(in: yourLabel)
    let characterIndex: Int = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    guard
        characterIndex < storage.length,
        let question = currentQuestion else {
            return
    }
    nameStrings.forEach {
        let range = displayText.getRange(OfText: $0)
        if range.contains(characterIndex) {
            /// Perform actions on click of this string
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can get the array of the simple "ilesh.panchal" insted of "(ilesh.panchal)".

Comment: Which library are you using for showing mention list when creating mention? have you created yourself or any repo?

Comment: I did not quite get you, but to answer your question, I have not used any repo/3rd party.
Is there any issue that you're facing?

Comment: I want to set UI same as the tweeter app when I mention a user. also, how can open mention user list event with the search result?

Comment: That(open mention user list) is an another question altogether @ilesh :) Try asking / searching for the same

Comment: Thanks, @Mansi :)

Answer (score 0):

As from your question, just hard-code parsing done below.

```
    let fullString = "@[Hema](hema_ramburuth), @[Ilesh P](ilesh.panchal), @[Lewis Murphy](lewis) how are you?"
    let allarray = fullString.split(separator: ",")
    let messageArray = allarray.last
    let message = messageArray?.split(separator: ")")
    let correctMessage = message?.last

    var allNames : String  = ""
    for namesString in allarray {
        if allNames.count > 0 {
            allNames += ", "
        }
        let name = String(namesString)
        allNames += name.slice(from: "@[", to: "]") ?? ""
    }
    if allNames.count > 0 {
        allNames += correctMessage ?? ""
    }
    print("Name and Message --- > \(allNames)")
```

Slicing string using String extension

```
extension String {

    func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {

        return (range(of: from)?.upperBound).flatMap { substringFrom in
            (range(of: to, range: substringFrom..<endIndex)?.lowerBound).map { substringTo in
                substring(with: substringFrom..<substringTo)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've printed output as below:

> Name and Message --- > Hema, Ilesh P, Lewis Murphy how are you?